# KOMA-Script: Use scrheadings on chapterpage, but only the footer (not the header)

Tags: header-footer, chapters, koma-script

I'm using the KOMA-Script and have page-numbers at the bottom of my document. The headline contains the chapter/section-name.
By default, the chapterpagestyle is plain (or empty). So I set it to "scrheadings", because I want the page numbers at the bottom of a chapter-page. But now I also get the headsepline on the chapter-page, which is not very beautiful.

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
% Head
\rohead{\raisebox{0.15em}{\textnormal \headmark}}
\rehead{\raisebox{0.15em}{\textnormal \headmark}}
\setheadsepline{.1pt}
% Foot
\cfoot{\raisebox{-0.5em}{ -- \, \textnormal{Page \thepage} \, --}}

% This is the line I want to modify:
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

% just for MWE
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Something}
        \Blindtext
        \Blindtext
    \chapter{Something else}
        \Blindtext
        \Blindtext
\end{document}
```

I commented the line which I assume has to be changed, but I did not figure out how…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `\cfoot` has an optional argument which specifies the plain style which is used for chapter pages. So you can simple do:

```
\cfoot[\raisebox{-0.5em}{ -- \, \textnormal{Page \thepage} \, --}]{\raisebox{-0.5em}{ -- \, \textnormal{Page \thepage} \, --}}
```

Here your modified mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
% Head
\rohead{\raisebox{0.15em}{\textnormal \headmark}}
\rehead{\raisebox{0.15em}{\textnormal \headmark}}
\setheadsepline{.1pt}
% Foot
\cfoot[\raisebox{-0.5em}{ -- \, \textnormal{Page \thepage} \, --}]{\raisebox{-0.5em}{ -- \, \textnormal{Page \thepage} \, --}}

% This is the line I want to modify:
%\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

% just for MWE
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Something}
        \Blindtext
        \Blindtext
    \chapter{Something else}
        \Blindtext
        \Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, it worked like a charm! :-) (I ommited a footsepline within my mwe (for simplicity). For those who are searching `\usepackage[plainfootsepline]{scrbook2}`) :-)

Comment: excellent, even after spending hours reading through the Koma Scirpt manual I had no idea the \cfoot had an optional argument for chapter pages. The advice here worked for me as well.